packages installation using pip command
I am trying to install all the 10 packages specified in requirements.txt in an environment.
I have installed using the following command
pip install -r requirements.txt

The packages are added successfully.
There is a scan that is done using the requirements.txt to check for vulnerabilities and risks and I get a report in the scan that during installation of the packages, some sub-dependency packages (from that 10) are of outdated version
How to push to install with all the sub-packages and all from the parent packages specified in the requirements.txt file to be force-installed to the newest version?
Will this command do the sub for the sub-list packages?
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

Please advise.
Also, some of the packages do not have license details tagged (such as MIT/ BSD etc.)

--upgrade-strategy=eager will also upgrade transitive dependencies:

Determines how dependency upgrading should be handled [default: only-if-needed]. "eager" - dependencies are upgraded regardless of whether the currently installed version satisfies the requirements of the upgraded package(s). "only-if-needed" -  are upgraded only when they do not satisfy the requirements of the upgraded package(s).


There must be specified versions of packages in your requirements.txt file like:
package_name==X.Y.Z

Removing the ==X.Y.Z part would install the latest version. But you may or may not encounter incompatibility issues. Give it a try.
Don't forget to first update your pip before doing so:
pip install -U pip


Thanks @s-b. I am getting scan reports for packages that are dependents of those specified in the requirements.txt. They are reported as 'OUTDATED'.


How to push to install with all the sub-packages and all from the parent packages specified in the requirements.txt file to be force-installed to the newest version?

You should not do this, especially since you are already concerned with risks. The maintainers of the package that you are installing wrote their own requirements.txt restricting the versions of their dependencies to those that are compatible. Ideally, the package you are installing has been tested for stability and reliability with the versions of their dependencies specified in ther requirements.txt. If you just use a different version you risk faulty behaviour which could be an obvious failure if APIs have changed, or it could "silently" fail, imagine a library having some API function with a keyword argument where the default changes.
If you absolutely need to have the newest version, then you need to write to the maintainers of the package that you are trying to install and ask them if they can change their requirements.txt and their code to be compatible with the newest version of their dependencies.
